# Puxar informações do usuário logado sem usar o Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session

Estou com uma aplicação desenvolvida com Laravel que possui alguns pequenos arquivos .php na pasta public que são carregados em uma determinada view.

Preciso puxar informações do usuário logado nesses arquivos, mas não consegui com o Auth::user(). Como posso fazer? Acredito que essas informações fiquem em uma session ou algo do tipo, mas não sei como recuperar.

Comment: Pasta public com arquivos `.php`, qual motivo de fazer assim?

Comment: é tipo um plugin de chat que está sendo usado na aplicação, a pasta dele fica na public e ele tem alguns templates e tals. https://www.magnoliyan.com/video-chat-pro